# Codepipeline with ECS

Tags: docker, microservices, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to prepare AWS Codepipeline + Codebuild configuration for Java maven2 projects. Everything works like a charm but I have some doubts how to use it right. My project consists of 4 modules. Each module is a microservice packed in Docker image. Should I have one pipeline for this project? Other way: one pipeline for each microservice?
Configuring Codepipeline using Cloudformation i found it can deploy only one Cluster*Service in Deploy Action for ECS.
How can I deploy all services using one pipeline? Is it good idea?

Best regards,
Maciej.

Answer (score 3):

The idea with microservices is that you can deploy them separately so you should have a separate pipeline for each microservice.

If you often need to deploy more than one then maybe your service boundary are wrong or you are in the pre-aplication realease when things are really messy.

Answer (score 0):

From code pipeline perspective you can have multiple ECS deploy actions in the same pipeline and deploy them parallelly or serially.